Need help making EditText views scrollable in Android
So I have these two EditText Views, one(id: input) where you enter your input and the other(id: output) shows you some output. Everything works just the way i want, except the two EditTexts aren't scrollable as in, I can't  scroll through and view the text vertically within both the EditText views. I want to make it so that whenever a user tries to scroll through either the input or the output EditText views they get shown whatever text is inside it in a scrolling fashion.
This is the xml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:backgroundTint="#FDFDFD"
    android:foregroundTint="#FBFBFB">

    <!-- Header -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/unscrollableHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="178dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:backgroundTint="#000000">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FDFCFC"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#F8F8F8"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.994">

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/goToSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="304dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#000000"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/baseline_app_settings_alt_24"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:onClick="openSettingsActivity"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- content -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/unscrollableHeader">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout5"
                android:layout_width="380dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#F8F8F8"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.521"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.326">

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="328dp"
                android:layout_height="242dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="560dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Paste your text here:"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input"
                    android:layout_width="319dp"
                    android:layout_height="174dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_view"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="start|bottom"
                    android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TextView"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.686" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/clearInput"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="236dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="#000000"
                    android:onClick="clearInputText"
                    android:text="Clear"
                    android:textColor="#FBFBFB"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
                    android:textColorHint="#FBFBFB"
                    android:textColorLink="#040404"
                    app:cornerRadius="5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:rippleColor="#979292" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
                android:text="Generate Summary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                android:layout_width="329dp"
                android:layout_height="236dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/submit">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Your Summary:"
                    android:textColor="#FFFDFD"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/output"
                    android:layout_width="319dp"
                    android:layout_height="174dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_view"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="start|bottom"
                    android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#040404"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.719" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/clipboard"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="256dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="#000000"
                    android:tint="#F8F8F8"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="?attr/actionModeCopyDrawable" />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/history"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="284dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="376dp"
                android:onClick="openHistoryActivity"
                android:text="History"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.784" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="276dp"
                android:layout_height="380dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/history"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/capture" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/uploadButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
                android:text="upload"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout5"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.637" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

I tried Experimenting with nested scrollView that did not work the way i thought it would. simply setting "android:scrollbars="vertical" doesn't work either, and I mean understandably so too.
